# How can I make HTML elements be constant, regardless of the current page size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am doing a practice program and I am trying to re-create the skill tree from the game Path of Exile. This requires me to arrange each of the nodes precisely and ensure they are the correct distance from one another. This would also ideally allow for the user to zoom in on the page and examine them more closely.

However, the fundamental aspects of HTML are making this seem to be impossible. The leftmost elements are always occupying the left edge of the page and the rightmost elements are always occupying the rightmost edge of the page, with them re-arranging themselves as the page size is adjusted.

Is there any way I can prevent that so the distance between the elements remain constant? I'm working with a grid and placing the elements inside of it.

I haven't been able to find a method for this kind of locking yet.

EDIT: As requested, here is the current relevant coding I have.

HTML code:

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, ifr);
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  background: rgb(76, 45, 45);
  padding: 0rem;
}

.grid-item {
  background: rgb(76, 45, 45)
}

.grid-item-1 {
  background: rgb(76, 45, 45);
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 1;
}

.grid-item-2 {
  background: rgb(76, 45, 45);
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 2;
}

.grid-item-3 {
  background: rgb(76, 45, 45);
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-1">
    <button onclick="buttonTest(1)">Test button 1 </button>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-2">
    <button onclick="buttonTest(2)">Test button 2 </button>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item-3">
    <button onclick="buttonTest(3)">Test button 3 </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2: Gary's answer on Absolute Positions is correct and exactly what I need. The button to mark an answer as correct isn't appearing for me, though.

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish but have you looked at [absolutely positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) your elements? You may need to recalculate some items following a resize event if that is to what you are referring when you write that the page size is adjusted.

Comment: You really should add your code to your question... Please edit your question and add the code that you are talking about...

Comment: Hi Gideon, welcome to SO! Although at some point we all wish to be clairvoyant, thusfar I have met no one who really was. Please post some [reprex], so people can see what you have been up to and try to find your issue...